# Renekton vs Teemo

Tags: league-of-legends

How do you avoid getting completely zoned by a teemo as renekton ?
His ranged pokes outrange anything you have in your arsenal as renekton, and even if you go in with e for a w-q combo you end up getting forced out because of his blind and his e damage.

Answer (score 3):

Stay in the bush and only come out to CS.
If he moves close E to him and stun him with W followed by Q and E again back into the bush. Depending on his reaction time he might/might not get his blind off. If you manage to stun this combo should deal quite a bit of damage to him.

Buy an early MR item since his blind and poison as well as his shrroms are both magic damage.

Ganks help before lvl 6 but after that a good teemo will be pretty much impossible to gank thanks to his mushrooms and his high movespeed.

The match up itself is pretty hard for Renekton or most melee top lanes since Teemo counters them.

Comment: Note that Renekton's stun is applied even if you are blinded by Te emo.

Answer (score 0):

get ganks, buy maw of malmortius first. Basically counterbuild the teemo and get ganks to shut him down. If you cant do that just farm safely at tower.

Answer (score 0):

Get magic resist so that his poison does not do as much damage and keep harassing him wen you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a decent Renekton, then you will buy magic res. I find shoes and 3(4) hp pots to be a good start though; followed by magic res and Maw of Malmortius. Tenacity boots with magic res also helps a bunch. After that, it's all about waiting for him to come too close, then `e-w-q-e`. After level 6 you can chose to keep fighting if you want, just make sure you get your important areas warded!

Answer (score 0):

### [Renekton](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Renekton)

### Early game

---

Stay in the brush as much as you can (try avoid to lose last hits on the creepers) and attack him. You'll fall behind in the start of the duel, but then you'll get ahead. save your cooldowns for this moment (or to escape if something goes wrong).

### Mid Game

---

Passing level 6 you will be able to do some extra damage and have extra survivability thanks to your ultimate. Try at all costs hit a mushroom if you are engaging into a fight versus Teemo. When you get close to him, he'll probably drop a mushroom at your feet (in front of him). use Slice to go to Teemo's back, Don't use dice unless you are sure you'll be able to avoid mushrooms. Wait for him to use blind, then you can stun him (so he'll be unable to hit you while you can't hit him. Keeping the fight at your favor) and use all your cooldowns, including your ultimate (when the blind is about to go off).

### General Tips

---

Renekton builds usually starts with atk dmg and/or arm pen. So your early game will be one of the most fearsome from all the champions, use it at your favor to keep teemo from getting last hits as much as possible.

After level 6, avoid the brush and keep an eye where he's putting his mushrooms, try keep him busy so he can't mine field your lane.

If he's building Ap or Hybrid Teemo, get some MR items. Be always aware of what your opponent is building.